# How to configure live tiles (calendar, etc) in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, live-tiles

I recently upgraded to Windows 10 and I'm using Live Tiles in the Start menu. Where can I configure what is shown?

I assumed there would be settings within the apps, but there's not. E.g. the calendar tile only shows events for the next 2 days. I want it to show the next 7 days. Is this possible?

Comment: The live tiles are going to be dynamic based on what is running, what you have launched, basically based on your usage.  What is displayed for the calendar is a separate issue.

Comment: How can my upcoming appointments, the weather or news of the world be influenced by what is running on my computer @Ramhound ? I don't really get your answer.

Comment: As you start different applications that have a live tile, what live tiles are displayed, will change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot find it in application options (look for a gear icon in application) then most likely tile content customization is not possible within given application.

This also applies to the Calendar app. Even with the biggest tile, only 3-4 events can be shown and 7 days won't fit*.

**There is an alternate way** to keep all information like next 7 days from the calendar at hand: arrange desired app(s) on separate desktop (use multi-desktop feature) so you can quickly check this "informational desktop" and return.

The check can be convenienty made using the keyboard. Related shortcuts are

- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to create desktop
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> to move view one desktop left
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to move view one desktop right

So with the calendar permanently open, you can use one shortcut to display it and one to hide it. Of course, the information at the tile (as you requested) could be reachable more easily, but on the other hand, with second desktop you are not limited by space of the tile and you can instantly peek at it whenever you need. **You gain flexibility beyond tile view** – better view configuration (think about more info apps at the same desktop) and immediate interaction – you can edit displayed week or to do list (or whatever else) right away.

---

*) Out-of-the-box tiles are keeping certain design rules, including look of icons, minimum spacings or minimum font sizes. In case of Calendar app, I think that displaying of 7 days on a tile would require very small font etc. Displayed among neighboring tiles, such a tile would look like a defaced piece. I think no designer will allow such a thing, and not only in area of user interface design. Maybe some 3rd-party developer can supply an app with ugly-but-extremely-useful tile, but I would not expect this from the Microsoft, they would be going against themselves.

Comment: Of course this is a well doing workaround, especially since Microsoft didn't limit the amount of virtual desktops afaik. Also it seems that there simply is no possibility to change the behaviour of live-tiles. I already requested this feature at the Microsoft feedbacksite. Thank you so far!

Comment: You are right in your Edit @miroxlav. Maybe amount of days is the wrong unit to measure. Amount of upcoming events would be more suitable, irrespective of how long they are in the future.

Comment: @Robin – pardon me, I've expressed myself impoperly. Number of items per tile (of any type: days, upcoming events, ... ) is the limit which cannot be exceeded if tile design doesn't have to be violated.

Comment: A max amount to fit the design rules is perfectly fine. But now i have a huge tile which is empty because my next appointments are more than 2 days in the future (weekend). THAT is what bothers me so much ;-)

Comment: @Robin - now I got your point. I did not notice it during testing because I had created one event per each day. :)